# Set unique ID to a react instance

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm currently making a react App that will be accessed through multiple dockerized Firefox instances.

One problem I have is that I must have a way to identify which container is using the react app.

What I mean is that I need a way to have something like a field where you'd put your ID, but of course automatically.

I was thinking of something like sending the ID through the link, but I don't know if it's possible or if there is another way.

Also I can't set random ID's, I need to be able to set it.

TL:DR : I need to set an ID to a react instance automatically

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can dynamically fetch docker instance id into your ENV and then use ENV to project the id into your react app

EDIT: Since you want to identify browser on which you are running your application on you can create a reference using a browser-fingerprint from a library like this -  [fingerprintjs](https://github.com/fingerprintjs/fingerprintjs)

or you can alternatively create cookies on first visit to remember the reference.

or if you really want to set a ID from react itself, you can create a Unix timestamp and use that as id, it wont be random so it wont conflict

EDIT 2:
You can also manually set a cookie from developer tools in firefox, check the add item button on top right
[image]

Comment: We do not deploy multiple reacts, we have one React server and multiple Firefox that access the same react address, so it wouldn't work

Comment: @Aleks got it, i have updated my answer, do give a voteup if it answers your question

Comment: Something I'm not sure about, the ID must come from the browser, not anything else and be something like : A1, A2, B5 etc....
The cookie solution is probably the closest one since it would work pretty much as I hope but it wouldn't work since I can't set the cookie through the browser, or at least I don't know how i'd do it

Comment: actually you can manually set a cookie in browser, check my edited answer. Hit upvote if it answers your question !